# Excel VSTO workbook object returning empty

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto

Excel VSTO add-in that puts a button in my ribbon.

I have pinpointed where the issue lies, but I don't know why this is giving me an error or how to fix it. Even more interesting, is that it works fine if I stay in the same instance of excel. I can run the add-in multiple times with no issues. Now open a new instance of excel and I get a COMException.

```
Excel.Workbook thisWorkbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

//...
//Run some code
//Run the below function (my function)

setTheseColumnHeaders(thisWorkbook.Worksheets[1], someList)

//Run some more code

Globals.ThisAddIn.Dispose(); //added this line to see if it would help, but didn't change anything.
```

This doesn't give me any issues the first time I run the add-in, but now the second time, `thisWorkbook` appears to be a null object, so calling `Worksheets[1]` on it causes an error.

Not sure why this is happening - if I open a new instance of excel, and try running the add-in, after running it once, it should create new objects, but I don't know why the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook` is returning an empty com object.

Here are the steps involved with my issue:

1. Open new instance of excel
2. Click the button in the ribbon to execute add-in
3. Custom form pops up asking the user for certain parameters
4. Next custom form pops up asking for some more input
5. Click ok on the form (from [4]) and the rest of the program executes.

Now, with that same sheet open that I just ran the VSTO for -

1. Open new instance of excel
2. Click the button in the ribbon to execute add-in
3. Custom form pops up asking the user for certain parameters
4. Next custom form pops up asking for some more input
5. Click OK form closes - nothing happens.

Now if I close both instances and try running the same parameters as the second time everything works fine.

Comment: How are you open second instance of excel? Because second workbook doesn't mean second instance.  You can have many workbooks open in one excel process, or in many excel processes,

Comment: I am running excel.exe again

Comment: It's not a guarantee theat it's not the same process. Did you check it it the task manager?

Comment: @AlexButenko so after a task manager check there is only one Excel.exe process that I am seeing. So, now I really am kind of confused as to what is going on

Comment: That means you have only one instance. It's normal for excel, it tries to put everything in one process.  It's not obvious how to start it separately, but it's doable

Comment: Well, so what does that mean for my issue then?

Comment: Code you provided is not enough and there is no information, haw do you open "new instance"

Comment: @AlexButenko not trying to open up a new instance of excel with the code, I am curious to know why I can only run the program once, and then if I open up another workbook (while the first one is open) and try to run my program it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know now what the problem is. As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activeworkbook.aspx) says, `_Application.ActiveWorkbook` can return null in some cases. So, when you open some pop-up window, it takes focus from excel, and there is no active workbook anymore. And maybe, if you have only one workbook, it can guess it is the only option to be active. But if you have two workbooks, it just can return you null. So I would recommend to store some variable with a reference to your workbook **before** opening popups.

Comment: Yeah so I actually do do that, but obviously you wouldn't have known that from what I posted. But I will try this a different way, you may have given me an ideo